# What is a better practice when defining a const NSString object in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i read colleagues' code in my team, i usually found there were two different types of definition for const NSString objects:

`static NSString const *`   and
`static NSString * const`

As far as i know, the former is a pointer point to a const `NSString` object, and the latter defines a const pointer to a `NSString` object.

My question is which is a better programming practice and a preferred way when defining a const `NSString` object in `objective-c`?

Thx.

Comment: As noted below, an NSString is immutable and need not itself be identified as `const`.  You presumably want the pointer to be `const`.

Comment: (Of course, a literal string is another option.)

Comment: what is your goal with the string? it is a value inside a viewcontroller, or an attribute of an entitiy? or you want to define a system wide value, for example a hostaddress, which you want to use in several classes ? or a value that will be set once at runtime but then shall be available througout the app lifecycle?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally,

```
static NSString * const
```

is a better choice.

Actually, `static NSString const *` is same to `static NSString *`, cause the string here is already immutable. *If you analyse it deeper, you'll notice that `const` is absolutely nothing to do with it, NSString is Objective-C's class, it wraps the actual value in C.*

**Note**: `NSString` is a constant type itself (there's a `NSMutableString` exists). You only need to define a const pointer for it if u want it to be a constant.

---

#### EDIT

```
static NSString * const var;       // 1
static NSString const * const var; // same to 1, first const is useless
static const NSString * const var; // same to 1, first const is useless
```

**CANNOT** do any modification.

```
static NSString * var;              // 2
static NSString const * var;        // same to 2, the const is useless
static const NSString * var;        // same to 2, the const is useless
```

**CANNOT** modify the value of var, but **CAN** modify the pointer.

```
static NSMutableString * const var; // 3
```

**CAN** modify the value of var, but **CANNOT** for the pointer.

```
static NSMutableString * var; // 4
```

**CAN** modify both the value & pointer.

---

#### EDIT 2

As @user3125367 mentioned,

> Immutability in Objective-C terms has nothing to do with constness in C.
>   ...
>   There are 3 orthogonal things: pointer constness, object field constness and object's high-level mutability.

I agree with him about it. NSString has a higher level (it also inherited form NSObject), const on it should have no effect in fact (not the same meaning about the *"no effect on immutable object"*). *But the complier might take care of it already.*

## NOTE:

```
var = @"a";  
var = @"b";
```

the code snippet above means the pointer changed, not the value. There's no way to modify the value of NSString instance (for NSMutableString, you can use some methods like `-appendString:` to modify the value).

If you use

```
static NSString const * var;
```

the final `var` will point to `@"b"`. Instead, if you use

```
static NSString * const var;
```

compiler will throw an error, and it's what we want: making the var unchangeable.

Comment: Offer a link here might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const . :)

Comment: I am missing the explanation that one notation means "constant pointer to data" while second is "pointer to constant data". Also there is a difference in usage. You can use "constant pointer" anywhere where "pointer" is expected but you can't use "pointer to constant data" in the same way.

Comment: Immutability in Objective-C terms has nothing to do with constness in C. One may write a custom container class that *is* a mutable/immutable cluster, *and* declares a public field that may be mutated unless const MyContainer *x is used. There are 3 orthogonal things: pointer constness, object field constness and object's high-level mutability. NSString just doesn't have any public fields.

Comment: @user3125367 yes, it makes sense, NSString is a wrap from C, const has nothing to do with it's mutability in fact.

Comment: @user3125367 i'm thinking that the complier might handles the const for Objective-C classes, just we don't realise it.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Const is compile-time specifier, it doesn't exist in runtime (except that the compiler is free to put static const data into ro section). Immutability is runtime property indeed. If you're about whether `const X *x; x->f = 0` does generate compile-time error, then I didn't check but pretty sure it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString const *str
```

means str is immutable.if you change str value for example str=str2, there's error occurs.

```
NSString *const str
```

means what str point to is immutable.You can change str = str2;

since NSString is immutable

```
NSString *const str
```

is equal to

```
NSString *str
```

Answer (score -2):

<s>I prefer `static const NSString *var;` because `static`and `const` are qualifiers for the NSString pointer.
Only the pointer is `const` not the NSString.</s>

The NSString will be constant because it is not mutable but a `const NSMutableString *s` will not make s mutable String become constant and so not modifiable. The pointer to the mutable String s will be constant and the compiler won't allow you to modify it.

Sorry for the inversion: Ken Thomases is right: `int * const Var;` means the pointer is constant and cannot be changed, but the data it points to can be changed. `const int * Var` means the data pointed to by Var cannot be changed.

Comment: can you please explain more clear the case if it is NSMutableString ?

Comment: Static const NSString * var seems a pointer to a NSString object , not a const pointer.

Comment: `static const NSString *var;` as @dadacomeon said, it's a pointer to a const string, and the string here is already immutable, so it's same to `static NSString * var;`.

Comment: If you declare `static NSString *var`, you can later assign another `NSString *` to var. The compiler will be OK. If you declare `static const NSString *var`, you won't be able to assign another `NSString *`to you var variable: the compiler won't be OK because it is declared `const`. And `static`is just here to specify that this varaible is only accessible inside the file it is declared in.

Comment: @dingua If you declare `static const NSMutableString *str`, str is a pointer to a NSMutableString. You can't make it point to another memory address than the initial value. But it point to a NSMutableString type object. You can't make it point to another object, but this object (the NSMutableString) can modify its value because it is 'mutable'.

Comment: @NicolasBuquet incorrect, `static const NSMutableString *str` is u can reset the pointer, but cannot modify the value though it's `NSMutableString` type, cause it's a `const NSMutableString`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Putting the const before the `*` means that thing which is pointed to is `const`. The pointer is not `const` and can be changed, which is not good for the desired result.

Comment: @dingua Sorry, Ken Thomases is right:`int * const Var;` means the pointer is constant and cannot be changed, but the data it points to can be changed.`const int * Var` means the data pointed to by Var cannot be changed.

Answer (score -2):

**// Demo.h**

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MyFirstConstant;
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const MySecondConstant;
```

// Demo.m

```
NSString *const MyFirstConstant = @"FirstConstant";
NSString *const MySecondConstant = @"SecondConstant";
```

Comment: Where is the explanation?