# App is referring to old values in constants file after updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, constants

I’m maintaining two constants files in my app where in which one file contains all the constants defined using `#define` and other file contains all the constants defined using:

```
static NSString const *holidaysearch = @"holidaySearch"
```

Basically I use them for forming the URL for server calls. Our app is already in app store. So in a update to my app that I published last week I have made changes to both constant file by modifying the values only.

For *e.g.*:

```
static NSString const *holidaysearch = @"getholidaySearch"
```

(When means in real time in my app I have changed a url). But when user is updating the app and running the app the constant is still referring to the old value (*i.e* holidaysearch) due to which we are facing some issues. But it's working fine when the user is installing latest version directly. So is there any concept of iOS caching the constants file while updating the app or anything else needed to be done? Suggest me fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by changing all of your #define constants to NSString * const. Also, `static NSString const *holidaysearch` should be static `NSString * const holidaysearch`. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000641/what-is-a-better-practice-when-defining-a-const-nsstring-object-in-objective-c) an explanation as to why.